# Paypal button redirecting on cart page in magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento, paypal, payment

Paypal button redirecting on cart page in magento 1.9.1, Our base currency is AED and we want to use paypal as a payment method but paypal dont support our currency so we added some codes in out site for currency conversion, seems like everything is fine but we are unable to checkout from paypal. when we click on paypal button it redirect on cart page again rather then paypal site. Please help what is that problem or how I can fix it.?

I found that error, PayPal gateway has rejected request. Currency is not supported (#10605: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

credits : @Boogz

Create the file Config.php in /app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

Step 1

Copy the file from /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php to /app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Config.php

Step 2

Look for the $_supportedCurrencyCodes

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB');
```

and add your currency that needs supporting to the end of the array

If your currecny is AED.

```
protected $_supportedCurrencyCodes = array('AUD', 'CAD', 'CZK', 'DKK', 'EUR', 'HKD', 'HUF', 'ILS', 'JPY', 'MXN',
    'NOK', 'NZD', 'PLN', 'GBP', 'SGD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'USD', 'TWD', 'THB', 'AED');
```

Source : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/payment/tweak_paypal_standard_for_non-supported_base_currency

Comment: Not working :( I have done same proccess as you said. but no luck)

Comment: try this extension in demo site:  https://github.com/Meabed/Paypal-Multi-Currency-Magento

Comment: I installed it but no luck. I am using Paypal Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout) is there any problem using this?

Comment: @rickads why dont you use `website standard method`.

Comment: disable the express checkout and check

Comment: @rickads may be its not showing because your base currency is not supported. try to chnage base currency to `us dollar` and check whether `website standard method` is showing or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

ENABLING PAYMENT STANDARDS

You can easily enable Payment Standards in Magento 1.9 by running the below database query:

update core_config_data set value = 1 where path = 'payment/paypal_standard/active';

DISABLE PAYPAL EXPRESS

update core_config_data set value = 0 where path = 'payment/paypal_express/active';

then it will work fine